# How do i perform join on 2 dataframes that have same number of rows but no matching column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, concatenation

I am trying to plot a histogram for missing NaN values across all features of a dataframe
For that i created a dataframe for missing NaN values

**Missing value Dataframe**

```
   0
-----
0  0
1  14
2  800
.
.
84 2344
```

Then i have this master dataframe that has multiple columns i am not concerned about since i want only the row names from this dataframe

**Master Dataframe**

```
     0  1
---------
F1   3  3
F2   4  3
.
.
F85  5  2
```

How can i merge/ concatenate these 2 dataframes where the final output should be like (Columns in master dataframe are irrelevant since i want to plot number of missing values across all features i.e. F1,F2,...F85)

```
    F1   0  
    F2   14 
    F3   800
    .
    .
    F85  2344
```

Comment: I can't see how anything is merged/concatenated in the output

Comment: @yatu the first columns seem to come from the second dataframe (its index I assume). Although you could try an improve the formatting a bit to make easier to understand and replicate Shalin.

Comment: Sure @CeliusStingher, re-formatted. Hope it is legible now..Correct,  a) features (Rows in this case) from dataframe 2 b) the missing values determined and shown in dataframe 1 need to be displayed in the merged dataframe.. IN the end, i will transpose the merged dataframe to plot a histogram using F1,F2,...F85 which will be columns after i transpose. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have result dataframe with index from second dataframe (master) and values from first dataframe (missing value dataframe)? In other words you want to join by row number, right?

Comment: yes, however there is no commonality in row names in the 2 dataframes as you see. So basically, i want to superimpose dataframe 1 on dataframe 2, so the missing value numbers correspond row by row to the row names (F1,F2...F85) in the merged dataframe..is that possible?

Comment: Sure, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asume your dataframes are `df1` (Missing value Dataframe) and `df2` (Master dataframe). Then you can try this:

```
df1.columns=['X']
res = df2.reset_index().join(df1.reset_index(), rsuffix='_r')[['index', 'X']].set_index('index')
print(res)
```

Result will be:

```
index      
F1        0
F2       14
F3      800
...
F85    2344
```

The idea is to use [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to replace index in both dataframes with row numbers and then merge dataframes

Comment: Works beautifully @Stepan ..just one thing..i had made a mistake earlier in my question.. the column index is '0' for dataframe 1 and not 'X' where  0 is the default index assignment..that is the reason when i performed the step you provided, it picks up row values mapped to column index '0' of dataframe 2 and not dataframe 1.. I tried to rename column name in dataframe 1 to something different, so your solution works, but rename didn't happen successfully. Any insights there?

Comment: You can add `df1.columns=['X']` before the `res=...`. I'll update answer

Comment: that works Stepan..thanks so much. Cant upvote your answer because i dont have that much reputation yet, but this works for my problem beautifully..

Comment: Done @Stepan .. i removed the index name and now there is a column name associated to the missing values ONLY..is there a way i can plot  a histogram with the F1,F2...F85 values on x axis and the missing values (represented by the column name) on y axis? can that be done based on the output generated in the answer above OR i need to add column name to the column represented by F1,F2..F85?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want to merge horizontally 2 dataframes, irrespective of indexes with the same amount of rows, different columns and indexes. Selecting only some columns out of some of them.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3], data={"a": [3,6,4]})

df2=pd.DataFrame(index=["a1","v2","x"], data={"x": [-3,136,-5], "y": ["x", "y", "c"]})

df3=pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2["x"].to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
```

Input:

```py
#df1
   a
1  3
2  6
3  4
#df2
      x  y
a1   -3  x
v2  136  y
x    -5  c
```

Output:

```py
#df3
   a    x
0  3   -3
1  6  136
2  4   -5
```

Comment: Thanks @Grzegorz, Skibinski - but i am looking to extract the row names from df2..Solution shared by stepan below solves my purpose

Comment: That's good, please mark @Stepan solution as an answer then ;)

Answer (score 0):

We can easily do this by using `concat` method of `pandas`.

`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['B2', 'B3', 'B6', 'B7'],
                    'D': ['D2', 'D3', 'D6', 'D7'],
                    'F': ['F2', 'F3', 'F6', 'F7']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

result = pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1, sort=False)
```

`

You will get the exact value as per your requirement.

Comment: sorry if it was not clear..i made some edits..there is no matching column which is the concern why i can't simply do a concat

Comment: You can change the column name in the above code than also you get the exact output.

Comment: I see, but even then, that would still look to concatenate on matching row names (and not row numbers), which is not in my ask..If you see Stepan's solution below involving reset_index, it solves the purpose..

Comment: In the above answer you have to import `pandas` library then it will solve the problem

Comment: ofcourse Vijayant. pandas libraries need to be imported, but what i am saying is the ask is different..it is not simple concatenation if you look at my initial question and the solution provided by Stepan...do have a look at it again..your solution kind of will do an inner join on the matching columns, which is not the ask